# Get current ThreadLocal Object in java

Tags: java

The way we can access current Thread by Thread.currentThread(); 
Is there a way we can access current ThreadLocal or we can get a reference of current ThreadLocal object?

Because I need to fetch the current Id set in the ThreadLocal.
and .get() is a non static method so i need an Object of ThreadLocal to call it.
Creating an new ThreadLocal Object will return me a new Id , not the same as the current Id set in ThreadLocal.

Comment: Normally whatever `ThreadLocal` object you need is a member of the class. Hard to understand why you don't already have one.

Comment: Which `ThreadLocal` **instance** are you talking about and in which class it is created?  What does the `id` represent?

Comment: @EJP say i am setting the Id somewhere outside . but i need to call it from a specific class. for which i need an object to call that get(). How is it possible to call that. If possible, Can you show me any example

Comment: @john16384 its created somewhere outside. and is being traversed by the thread throut the request. but i am not able to fetch it from outside

Comment: It is exactly the same as accessing anything else. The fact that it's a `ThreadLocal` makes no difference whatsoever. You call `myThreadLocal.get()` to get the instance for the current thread. You seem to be asking how to get `myThreadLocal` from some other class, which is just normal Java coding. No mystery about it.

Comment: @EJP are you reffering to ThreadLocal myThreadLocal=new ThreadLocal? creating an object like this?

Comment: For example, yes.

Comment: @EJP it will create a new ThreadLocal object. we can not access the same ThreadLocal. I already tried it !!!!

Comment: You said you already have it created in some other place. So *access it.* From that place. What on earth is the difficulty with that?

Comment: @EJP the thing is i am not able to access that. because i am totaly unware of it where by which means its created. i just have a knowledge that its created

Comment: So you can't access it. Nothing further to discuss. You seem to have a misconception here. There is no such thing as 'the current `ThreadLocal` object'. There are as many as you like. What there is is the current object *returned* for the current thread by `ThreadLocal.get()` when called on an instance of `ThreadLocal` that can be accessed by that thread. Not the same thing.

Comment: @EJP sad to know this  , but Thank you.

Comment: 'Sad to know' that you can't access an inaccessible variable? Why? That's what access control is *for*.